# Авторизация на сайте в QWebEngine

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qwebengine

Я создаю standalone-приложение для ВКонтакте, нужно реализовать OAuth авторизацию, но проблема в том, что при нажатии на кнопку "Войти" меня редиректит обратно на эту же страницу. Проблема, кажется, в том, что не сохраняются данные об авторизации(cookies, заголовки или что-то ещё).
Код:

```
import vk
import re
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5 import QtWebEngine
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QMainWindow

app = QApplication(sys.argv)


def authorize(token):
    print(token)


def url_changed(url):
    new_url = url.toString()
    if re.match(r'^.+access_token.+$', new_url):
        token = re.match(r'.+access_token=(.+)\&.+', new_url).group(1)
        authorize(token)
    else:
        print(new_url, 'doesn\'t match')


app_id = '6641802'
link = "https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?" + \
      f"client_id={app_id}&" + \
       "display=page&" + \
       "redirect_uri=https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html&" + \
       "scope=messages&" + \
       "response_type=token&" + \
       "v=5.80"

QtWebEngine.QtWebEngine.initialize()
web = QWebEngineView()
web.load(QUrl(link))
web.urlChanged.connect(url_changed)
web.show()


sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Замечу, что если перейти по этой ссылке через обычный браузер, там всё работает нормально.

Comment: Для qt4 / pyside делал подобное, но автоматизированно: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/6c64ecb4a6cea678892edd0a6db2bbc23d7e020e/login_vk.com.py

Comment: `Доступ к личным сообщениям
Приложению будут доступны Ваши личные сообщения, а также возможность отправлять сообщения от Вашего имени.` что-то мне сыкотно давать доступ вашему приложению :) Проверил через свое приложение (5356487), у которого нет никаких требований -- access_token вытащило

Comment: Немного поигрался с кодом и работает для выбранных приложений: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/7f659fefc2d37522932d3c4dff9282b7a35a6a5c/qt__pyqt__pyside__pyqode/pyqt5__QWebEngineView__get_access_token__from_append_application.py